# Enable to login into the application in Django tests

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, postgresql, unit-testing

I am writing the test cases to my application. Please find below code snippet of tests.py

```
class TestGetDetailsPositive(SimpleTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
      self.credentials = {
        'username': '****',
        'password': '****'
      }

@responses.activate
def test_get_details(self):
    self.client.login(username='****', password='****')
    response = self.client.get('/accounts/selectdetails/')
    self.assertContains(response, 'National', status_code=200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'accounts/select-details.html')

def test_view_url_exists_at_desired_location(self):
    url = reverse('selectdetails')
    self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func.view_class, SelectDetails)
```

I am getting below error as follows.

```
AssertionError: Database queries to 'default' are not allowed in SimpleTestCase subclasses. Either subclass TestCase or TransactionTestCase to ensure proper test isolation or add 'default' to accounts.tests.tests.TestGetBanksPositive.databases to silence this failure.
```

Database configuration looks like below

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': '****',
    'USER': '****',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
    'HOST': '****',
    'PORT': '****',
}
}
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: change `SimpleTestCase` to `TestCase`

Comment: Tried changing SimpleTestCase to TestCase but got the error "django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'Other' value must be either True or False."]"